# Find limit of sequence. Hint says that logarithm might be helpful.

Tags: limits, logarithms

I have hard time with this one:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1*4*...*(3n+1)}{2*5*...*(3n+2)}
$$
Hint says that using natural logarithm may be (but does not have to) be useful.
Unfortunately this hint is not enough for me, so maybe someone could come up with something better.

Comment: It seems like that the denominator always has bigger terms than the numerator...

Comment: Perhaps use the fact $\log(1+x) \leq x$ for all $x >-1$. And $\log((3n+1)/(3n+2)) = \log(1+x_n)$.

Comment: @imranfat : The ratios are less than 1 but that is not always enough.  Note that $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{n^2+1} > 0$.

Comment: @Michael. Yes that is true, but it was only a start. An observation that the answer ought not to be divergent...I did not imply that the answer was zero (though I was inclined to believe so, but couldn't back it up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\log\left(\frac{\prod_{k=0}^{n}(3k+1)}{\prod_{0=1}^{n}(3k+2)}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{3k+2}\right)$$

and for $z<1$

$$\frac{-z}{1-z}\le \log (1-z)\le-z$$

Then, compare the series with the harmonic series.

Comment: I just want to be sure. Is the answer 0?

Comment: Yes.  Well done.  The answer is indeed zero.